# Regarding HTML 5 topic name SVG

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, webkit

In the following code why do we use the `webkit` and `ms` keywords?

```
#svgelem {
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-20%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-20%);
        transform: translateX(-20%);
}
```

Comment: CSS vendor prefixes or CSS browser prefixes are a way for browser makers to add support for new CSS features in a sort of testing and experimentation period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** The `ms-` and `webkit-` keywords are used so each of the different CSS processors versions (microsoft (ms) and webkit) know how to handle that line. This is because of experimental features, like transform, being added by each of the CSS processors at different times.

The typical use of a block of CSS like this is used to move an element to the centre of it's parent object on the horizontal axis.

The idea is to move the element to so the left edge is in the middle of the parent:

```
#svgelemn {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Now that the element is just to the right of the middle (remember that it's the left edge that is in the middle), you need to move the element to the left by 50% of it's own width (not it's parents width). Because we're moving the element to the left, we also need to invert the percentage so it's negative (-50%). So now you add the transform section:

```
#svgelemn {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); /* Webkit specific transform */
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%); /* Microsoft specific transform */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* Generic transform (all evergreen browsers) */
}
```

The code that you have only makes a final adjustment of only 20%, so that's not quite the middle.

You can see an example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waOZJq). You can see how the top element is in the middle, while the original code makes it slightly off centre.